# Gitlab pipeline fails since the package.json has windows commands

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cypress, pipeline

I am working on a cypress project. The package.json has commands to delete old report folder and create new folder with same name.

I achieve this by using windows commands in package.json:

> “Clean-reports”: “rmdir /s /q cypress\reports && mkdircypress\reports”
> “Test”:”npm run Clean-reports && cypress run”

But when running this project on gitlab pipeline It gets stuck on rmdir command.

How do we achieve directory deletion and creation when running tests over gitlab pipeline ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), you have 200+ Linux command accessible in `<Path\to\GIt>\usr\bin`

That includes command `rm.exe`

Your `Clean-reports` steps can then become:

```
rm -Rf cypress\reports && ...
```

That command would be interpreted in a Linux environment.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @VonC. I now realise that docker runs on linus so the windows commands in my package.json wont work there.

Comment: @buckybarns yes, but you can use linux command even on Windows. That is what my answer illustrates.

Comment: I get the following error on using linux commands on windows: 'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\CypressProject
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c rm -R -f cypress/reports && rm -R -f cypress/output && mkdir cypress/output        

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

Comment: @buckybarns Is your PATH set correctly? Does typing rm works in a CMD? (and do you have installed Got for Windows?)

Comment: No. the rm command does not works in command prompt. Is there a way to make it work ?

Comment: @buckybarns Yes, as mentioned in the answer: modify your PATH to reference usr/bin from the Git installation PATH. (https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/)

Comment: Got it. Thank you @VonC